# Clever way to match elements in one data frame to elements in another data frame?

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, match

Say I have two columns `x = c("a", "c", "g")` and `y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")`.

x is a column in dataframe1 and y is a column in dataframe 2. dataframe1 does not necessarily match dataframe 2 in dimension.

I want to return the row of y that contains x. So for example, I would like to get 1, 3, 7.

I tried something clumsy like `items = which(dataframe1$x == dataframe2$y)` but obviously that doesn't work. I know I can do loop through `dataframe1$x` and match it to `dataframe2$y`, but it seems like there should be a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right tool. You just weren't using it correctly. `==` will match a single value. When you want to match one vector with another, use either `match` or `which` with `%in%` (and *not* with `==`).

Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("a", "c", "g"))
df2 <- data.frame(y = letters[1:7])
match(df1$x, df2$y)
# [1] 1 3 7
which(df2$y %in% df1$x)
# [1] 1 3 7
```